# Ubuntu 12.04 can't detect internal mobile broadband (Gobi 2000)

Tags: hardware, mobile-broadband

Hi I have been trying Ubuntu to detect and connect using the buit in mobile broadband capability in my HP 110 netbook but until now nothing seems to work

Output of `lspci` command:

```
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
01:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8132 Fast Ethernet (rev c0)
```

Output of `lsusb` command:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1fea:0008 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 03f0:2a1d Hewlett-Packard
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 03f0:241d Hewlett-Packard Gobi 2000 Wireless Modem (QDL mode)
```

So far I have been trying what is intended on several pages, trying to update firmware using wine and then moving .mda or whatever files the update package GobiInstaller.mdi throws out. The results are always the same: After running

Output of  `wine msiexec /a GobiInstaller.msi /qb TARGETDIR="c:\temp"`:

```
fixme:advapi:GetCurrentHwProfileA (0x33fba8) semi-stub
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationA (hwnd=0x13e250,       filter=0xf7e984,flags=0x00000001) returns a fake device notification handle!
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0 
fixme:advapi:RegisterEventSourceW ((null),L"Bonjour Service"): stub
fixme:advapi:ReportEventA (0xcafe4242,0x0004,0x0000,0x00000064,  (nil),0x0001,0x00000000,0x79e58c,(nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:ReportEventW (0xcafe4242,0x0004,0x0000,0x00000064,  (nil),0x0001,0x00000000,0x12e6d0,(nil)): stub
fixme:winsock:WSAIoctl WS_SIO_UDP_CONNRESET stub
fixme:winsock:WSAIoctl -> SIO_ADDRESS_LIST_CHANGE request: stub
fixme:iphlpapi:DeleteIpForwardEntry (pRoute 0x79e920): stub
fixme:iphlpapi:CreateIpForwardEntry (pRoute 0x79e958): stub
fixme:advapi:ReportEventA (0xcafe4242,0x0004,0x0000,0x00000064,  (nil),0x0001,0x00000000,0x79e58c,(nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:ReportEventW (0xcafe4242,0x0004,0x0000,0x00000064, (nil),0x0001,0x00000000,0x12e6d0,(nil)): stub
fixme:service:EnumServicesStatusW resume handle not supported
fixme:service:EnumServicesStatusW resume handle not supported
fixme:advapi:ReportEventA (0xcafe4242,0x0004,0x0000,0x00000064,(nil),0x0001,0x00000000,0x79e58c,(nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:ReportEventW (0xcafe4242,0x0004,0x0000,0x00000064,   (nil),0x0001,0x00000000,0x12e6d0,(nil)): stub
fixme:netapi32:NetGetJoinInformation Semi-stub (null) 0x79e644 0x79e63c
fixme:winsock:WSAIoctl WS_SIO_UDP_CONNRESET stub
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action   L"_693CD41C_A4A2_4FA1_8888_FC56C9E6E13B" returned 1603
err:rpc:I_RpcGetBuffer no binding
err:rpc:I_RpcGetBuffer no binding
andres@andres-HP-Mini-110-1100:~/.wine/drive_c/Qualcomm$ fixme:advapi:ReportEventA   (0xcafe4242,0x0004,0x0000,0x00000064,(nil),0x0001,0x00000000,0x79e588,(nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:ReportEventW (0xcafe4242,0x0004,0x0000,0x00000064, (nil),0x0001,0x00000000,0x12e6d0,(nil)): stub
```

And creates 2 empty folders, I have been trying hard and I am not sure if I am doing it the way it should be.

Comment: Please run `sudo lspci` so that we can see which card is built in.

Comment: 00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
01:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8132 Fast Ethernet (rev c0)

Comment: Hi thanks, above last lines after running sudo lspci

Comment: I'm sorry, while those cards are mostly connected via PCI, you have to execute `sudo lsusb`. I just checked back on my notebook. Could you please do that?

Comment: Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1fea:0008  
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 03f0:2a1d Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 03f0:241d Hewlett-Packard Gobi 2000 Wireless Modem (QDL mode)

Comment: @Anega - please remember to edit your question with new information such as above - reading this stuff in comment form is very difficult.  Thanks.

Comment: @ fossfreedom, thanks Next one will be on question side